# Cannot open source file in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-c++

Currently, I am trying to make a simple out put and input game using `<iostream>` but whenever I type `#include <iostream>` an error pops up saying "cannot open source file "iostream."" I have tried to copy the file path, but personally, I have no idea how to do that, even with tutorials.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome human!\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you respond on how to do the file directory, do explain like you are trying to explain it to a c++ beginner since I recently started. :)

Comment: Open the Visual Studio Installer, click modify, and make sure that Desktop development with C++ is checked. I don't believe it is installed by default.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the project after VS creation? 
I am unable to reproduce your problem. I have created a new project using VS console app template (also Windows desktop wizard). I ran both without any problem.
I would suggest you do the same. Create a console project and run it without any changes